# Optimal Implementation Choice for Producer-Consumer in Java

Tags: java, performance, producer-consumer

I am looking for an optimal producer-consumer implementation in Java with the following aspects:

1. Producer reads from server1 socket, and writes to a shared buffer, as well as another server 2 socket:

   > Server1 -> Server2 + shared buffer
2. Consumer reads from a shared buffer, and writes to server3 socket:

   > Shared Buffer -> Server3
3. **Writes to shared buffer from Server 1 should be non-blocking** (i.e. if the buffer is full it should not block the communication with Server 2).

I have considered the following options:

1. Java NIO Pipe
2. `ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Byte>` queue
3. `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream`
4. I assume buffer can have a pre-allocated memory to avoid dynamic memory allocation overhead? Or should that not be a concern? If so what would be a fast implementation.

What would be the fastest?

I have already tried out `PipedInputStream` and `PipedOutputStream`. My overhead compared to just forwarding data from server1->server2 was more than 12% this seemed excessive, which is why I came up with more options.

The specific part of the code already implemented, which is in the critical region (pertains to performance) is as follows in `CommunicateToServerAndPipe`:

```
 public void run() {
        try {
            String line = null;

            final byte[] request = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;

            //read from server 1 socket
            while (isRunning && (bytesRead = in.read(request)) != -1) {
                //write to server 2 socket
                out.write(request, 0, bytesRead);
                out.flush();
                //write to shared buffer pipe
                this.register.pos.write(request, 0, bytesRead);
            }
     register.kill();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        if(ex instanceof SocketTimeoutException) {
            // The socket simply timed out. Kill, then exit.
            register.kill();
            return;
        }
        this.kill();
    }
}
```

I have made my initial code available [here](https://github.com/nipunarora/JavaTCPReplicationProxy).

Comment: You seem to have quite specific communication needs. You may be interested in investigating more "full-blown" solutions like message-queue services. While those may provide less speed, they guarantee that no data is lost and are usually extensively tested

Comment: @Vogel612 - could you give examples? Also I am not interested in blocking systems for data transfer from Server 1 ->shared buffer (should be non-blocking) to ensure speed for Server 1 -> Server 2